# how to change color of list view row after populating using arrayadapter

Tags: android, android-listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

i am creating an android app in which i am inserting countries into the list view i want to change the color of top row of list view.

i am using array adapter to populate the list view anyone please help me how i can color the top row of list view after populating here is my code

```
 mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

 mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

 Collections.reverse(values);
```

where "values" is arraylist

now i am doing this

```
public class SpecialAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
```

{

```
public SpecialAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

}

```
 SpecialAdapter ad= new SpecialAdapter(this, R.id.scanning_listView, values);
```

this is correct?

Comment: You need to have a class extending `BaseAdapter` and then override the `getView()` to achieve this.

Comment: aniruddha tm?? ok let me try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_list, null);

        if (position == 0) {     
           view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);      //0 (zero), because you want to change the color of first row
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Override ArrayAdapter and override getView method there.

So if your adapter is something like this:

```
  public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
```

Your ListActivity will change like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new MyAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
```

Check this for [example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_adapterown)

Comment: any other way to do this?

Comment: Nope. If you want a tutorial please check http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/

Comment: thanks aniruddha will you please tell me what is from and to?

Comment: Where is from and to? There's one more link to example in the answer.

Comment: http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/ in this link

Comment: final View view = View.inflate(this, android.R.layout.list_content, null); this line show error "The method inflate(Context, int, ViewGroup) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments"